# Gamecenter: com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated

Tags: objective-c, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Many question have been posted about this problem, which appears in the console after you press done on a `Gamecenter VC`. So, I'm gonna bring it back to attention because it's still occurring, and the other questions don't have answers:

> plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated

My code:

Authentication in `viewDidLoad`:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
    if (viewController != nil)
    {
        [self presentViewController:viewController
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    }
};
```

Submitting score and opening leaderboard in an `IBAction`:

```
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
if (localPlayer.authenticated) {

    NSUInteger highscore = [self retrieveHighscore];

    GKScore *gkScore = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"Leaderboard" player:localPlayer];
    gkScore.value = highscore;
    [GKScore reportScores:@[gkScore] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];

    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil) {
        gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        gameCenterController.leaderboardTimeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        gameCenterController.leaderboardIdentifier = @"Leaderboard";
        [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Thanks in advance.